# Convert Byte array to the original file in javascript

Tags: .net, wcf, download, client, arrays

I am sending a Byte array which was originally a binary in the database. the processes of sending the byte array is fine, but the problem is how can I handle this byte array.

1) can I handle it using javascript, I mean can I retrieve the byte array and convert it back to its original state. if yes how ?

2) if no what other way I can do that.

What I want to do is to make the client side able to download files from the WCF without using a stream, I don't need stream because I know that the downloaded and uploaded files are small in size.

Comment: You could try sending a base64 encoded version of your files and use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to download them.

Comment: how can i return base64 using wcf

Comment: base64 are strings, so all you have to do is invoke [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) with your byte array. Please note that data URIs are only supported in modern browsers, but I don't think that JavaScript has any other mechanism to do this this sort of things.

Comment: I can see that but this is problem I need to support IE 7 and above, and I don't mined using any JavaScript library if it can provide this functionality. I also tried what you said I changed the byte to base64 string and return the string back but nothing happened, i Just got a base64string back