# Convert byte[] to file javascript

Tags: javascript, file, arrays

I have the byte array in javascript. How convert this array to file for upload?

Comment: Is this what you are after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603307/convert-byte-array-to-the-original-file-in-javascript

Comment: For upload? Why would you want to convert anything? Just send it via AJAX and do whatever you want with it on the server side.

Comment: Some more details about what you want will help.

Comment: There is HTML5 solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/23451726/2587343

Answer (score 1):

you create a file like this

```
new File([you byte here], 'name of your file', { type: 'you extention', lastModified: new Date() });

if the your byte is string 

  new File([this.base64ToArrayBuffer(you string)], 'file name', { type: this.handleFileDataType(DocExtension), lastModified: new Date() });



 base64ToArrayBuffer = (base64) => {
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
      var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
      bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
  }



 handleFileDataType = ext => {
    switch (ext) {
      case 'pdf':
        return 'application/pdf';
      case 'jpg':
        return 'image/jpeg';
      case 'jpeg':
        return 'image/jpeg';
      case 'png':
        return 'image/png';
      case 'tiff':
        return 'image/tiff';
      case 'docx':
        return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your question is that you have a Byte Array and you want to write these Byte Array to a file and upload it to server.

No, It is not possible in JavaScript because JavaScript doesn't have access to writing files as this would be a huge security risk.