# How to save a text to file and read it again but save as binary in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, io, binary

I'm building a file saver from a string using FileSaver.js [from a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23452051/5480251)

```
let byteChars = atob("my string");
let byteNumbers = new Array(byteChars.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteChars.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);
}
let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var data:Blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
var filename:string = filename + '.myext';
saveAs(data, filename, true);
```

Then I have to read it back to `"my string"` using Javascript's FileReader:

```
let fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = (e:FileReaderEvent) => {
    let result:any = e.target.result;
    //I don't know what I have to do with this type of data to get "my string" back
    };
fr.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Comment: Why are you base64 decoding "my string" here: `atob("my string");` ?

Comment: I got it from http://stackoverflow.com/a/23452051/5480251 this, I'm not sure if I can eliminate it, but "my string" here is the result from CryptoJS return for me, it has been encrypted.

Comment: _"but save as binary in javascript"_ What do you mean by "binary" here? What is purpose of using `Uint8Array`, `Blob`,  `'.myext'` file extension? You could save text content as file using `data URI`

Comment: @guest271314 It mean I don't want to save my text as plain text, `.myext` is a file extension.

Comment: Is requirement to save text as `base64` string?

Comment: @guest271314 I want to save it as binary file, which is not readable for human but for the machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, Updated

write file

```
let byteChars = atob("my string");
let byteNumbers = new Array(byteChars.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteChars.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);
}
let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var data = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
saveAs(data, "myfile.abc");
```

read file

```
<input type="file">
<script>
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
   document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" + btoa(e.target.result);
 });
  document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
  .addEventListener("change", function(e) {
     reader.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0])
  })
</script>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/0KVhXnd0JpysplDLcAlC?p=preview

---

You can use `TextEncoder()`, `TextDecoder()` or `FileReader()`, `.readAsBinaryString()`

```js
var str = "my string";
var encoder = new TextEncoder();
var encodedBytes = encoder.encode(str);
// do file save stuff
var decoder = new TextDecoder();
var decodedBytes = decoder.decode(encodedBytes);

console.log(encodedBytes, decodedBytes);

// alternatively, using `FileReader()`
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  console.log("FileReader result:", reader.result)
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(new Blob([encodedBytes]))
```

Comment: Hi, after do that, i got string like this: `U2FsdGVkX19F/TFrAgVg1vqS1eO1UXbDjYLY`, can it convert to some thing like this `ÊÀ,V˜õèeò+p¢¶ó¯£·ªÞY®Õß.`?

Comment: _"Hi, after do that, i got string like this: U2FsdGVkX19F/TFrAgVg1vqS1eO1UXbDjYLY, can it convert to some thing like this ÊÀ,V˜õèeò+p¢¶ó¯£·ªÞY®Õß."_  What is "like this" string? How did did you retrieve the characters?

Comment: I mean it still a readable string, not like this http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4402/oju5gjbo_png.htm

Comment: Where was string at linked image retrieved from?

Comment: Yes I do, and I get string like `U2FsdGVkX19F/TFrAgVg1vqS1eO1UXbDjYLY` when I save to file and open it to read. I mean the type of string, not the data itself

Comment: It is possible to retrieve original string back, though space character `" "` at `"my string"` would not be preserved. There is probably a method which would maintain space character. Would a solution which returns `"mystring"` at `FileReader` meet requirement?

Comment: Yes, I can get it back and start to work, but I need it presents as binary instead of encoded string.

Comment: @NamPham _"but I need it presents as binary instead of encoded string"_ What do you mean by "binary instead of encoded string"? [`TextEncoder().encode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/encode) returns a [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Uint8Array) which is a [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#Syntax) _"A TypedArray object describes an array-like view of an underlying binary data buffer."_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116148/discussion-between-nam-pham-and-guest271314).