# Save image/video to html local filesystem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filesystems, html5-filesystem

Saving text and text based blobs is easy enough with the HTML5 local filesystem API.  But how can I save binary files like images/video?  Like if I have input

```
<input class="LoadMedia" type="files" multiple>
```

And access it through jquery...

```
$('.LoadMedia').on('change', function() {
    var file = $(this)[0].files[0];
    // Do stuff to store binary file in local filesystem under predetermined path here
}
```

How can I store the file assuming I already have a filesystem initialized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving binary data as file using JavaScript from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451726/saving-binary-data-as-file-using-javascript-from-a-browser)

Comment: store it in indexeddb