# How can I create file from application/octet-stream data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have a REST API that returns application/octet-stream as MediaType and now I need to create a file and download it in client side!

```js
$("#export-space-excel-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#export-excel-space-dialog").hide();
    $("#export-excel-space-progress-dialog").css("display","");
    $("#export-excel-space-progress-dialog").show();
    $.ajax({
        url :  AJS.contextPath() + "/export/excel/space/"+spaceKey,
        type : "GET",
        data : {data1:data1},
        responseType: 'application/octet-stream',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'test.xlsx');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
            $("#export-excel-space-progress-dialog").hide();
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js, it may help.

Comment: is there any other method without using library ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23451803/9021949

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving binary data as file using JavaScript from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451726/saving-binary-data-as-file-using-javascript-from-a-browser)

Comment: why not just direct the browser to the address and let it handle the download?

Comment: @KirillStepanov thank you

Comment: @pschichtel how can i do it ?

Comment: @SamerSBOUI `window.location.href = "/export/excel/space/"+spaceKey`

Comment: i gonna try it thnx ;)