# Angular 7 download PDF file from POST

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to download a PDF file that is returned by a POST request:
Here is my Angular method:

```
  sendPost: void {
  const options = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/export', JSON.stringify(this.filter), 
    options )
      .subscribe((next) => console.log(next));
  }
```

And the Java backend that generates the PDF:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/export/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFilteredPDF(@RequestBody PdfExportFilter filter) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    StructureExporter writer = new FilteredPdfExporter(filter);
    Path filePath = Paths.get(writer.getBaseTempDir() + "/filteredExport.pdf");
    writer.exportData();
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(readPdfBytes(filePath), getHttpHeaders("_filtered_export"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How can I save the returned `byte[]` into  a PDF file so it gets downloaded to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the data you get from the post and create, and follow this solution to create a downloadable file

[Saving binary data as file using JavaScript from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451726/saving-binary-data-as-file-using-javascript-from-a-browser)

so the data should be the `next` from `console.log(next)`

in typescript it should be

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style.display = 'none';

const blob = new Blob(next, {type: "octet/stream"}),
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.href = url;
a.download = name;
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```